# How much incoming traffic can I process on a network card with two 100GbE ports?

Tags: networking, mellanox

How much incoming traffic can I process on a network card with two 100GbE ports(Mellanox X5)? Is it 100Gbs or 200Gbs incoming traffic?

Comment: It is 100 Gbps per interface, but understand that a single flow will use a single interface. If you bond with round-robin balancing, you can actually decrease performance due to things like out-of-order packet delivery, and it is death to real-time protocols, such as VoIP or video. Per-flow balancing (much preferred) will use 200 Gbps in aggregate, but you will need multiple flows to achieve that.

Comment: Is this true for Mellanox MCX516A-CCAT ConnectX-5 EN?

Comment: You are asking this question on the wrong SE network. [so] is for programming questions. You can ask general PC questions on [su].

Comment: Thx, reask is here: https://superuser.com/questions/1546738/how-much-incoming-traffic-can-i-process-on-a-network-card-with-two-100gbe-ports